# How to get current band set from android device/adb when its in not attched to BTS(airplane mode)

Tags: android, adb, telecommunication, lte

We have set our band to LTE B3 using service mode in Samsung galaxy S5 (*#0011#).
We are able to navigate to NAS and it protocols and then set band as LTE B3. But we couldn't validate whether it came to effect or not. It's showing as no service in airplane mode. How to get the band set on UE before its getting attached to network

We have checked in service mode and build.prop of UE as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can see NAS messages, look at the UE Capability Info message and see if your particular S5 supports Band 3. Not all variants support this band.

Comment: Thanks jeff. S5 supports that band.. ,my doubt is how to get the set band in ue (on airplane mode),using adb or any other messages.